# HTML/CSS - Divs wont align correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align these divs correctly but they are repositioning themselves at will! I'm trying to align `balance` horizontally with `history` whilst `transact` is aligned vertically below `balance`.

Edit: `.button` style is irrelevant.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-page-content">
<div id="balance">
   <u>Balances</u>
<div class="total-balance">
    Total Balance: 
</div>
<div class="a-balance">
    Balance:
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a>
    </div>
<div class="b-balance">
    Balance:
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="transact">
</div>
<div id="history">     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-page-content {
   max-width:960px;
   margin:auto;
   max-height: 500px;
   padding-top:25px;
   height:100%;
}

#balance {
    font-family:Lato;
    background-color:#00253F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:130px;
    width:52%;
    float:left;
}

#transact {
    font-family:Lato;
    background-color:#00253F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:130px;
    width:52%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#history {
   background-color:#00253F;
   width:32%;
   height:300px; 
   float:right;
}

.total-balance {
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-family:Lato;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    font-size:14px; 
    height:16px;
}

.a-balance {
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-family:Lato;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    font-size:14px; 
    height:16px;
}

.b-balance {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    font-family:Lato;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    font-size:14px; 
    height:16px;
}
```

The result of the above code or Checkout [**This Demo**](http://jsbin.com/pudepelani/1/)

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move history above transact in your html:

```
 <div id="history">Hist
 </div>
 <div id="transact">Trans
 </div>
```

```css
#main-page-content {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 100%;
}
#balance {
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #00253F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 52%;
  float: left;
}
#transact {
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #00253F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 52%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#history {
  background-color: #00253F;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  color: #fff
}
.total-balance {
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-family: Lato;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 16px;
}
.a-balance {
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-family: Lato;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 16px;
}
.b-balance {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: Lato;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-page-content">
  <div id="balance">
    <u>Balances</u>
    <div class="total-balance">
      Total Balance:
    </div>
    <div class="a-balance">
      Balance:
      <a href="#" class="button">Deposit</a>
      <a href="#" class="button">Withdraw</a>
    </div>
    <div class="b-balance">
      Balance:
      <a href="#" class="button">Deposit</a>
      <a href="#" class="button">Withdraw</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="history">Hist
  </div>
  <div id="transact">Trans
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question but you got in before me! Haha.

Comment: @Corona Sometimes its the really simple stuff that trips us up

Comment: You also didn't close your <div id="main-page-content"> if the HTML markup you posted is verbatim.

Comment: @Corona I also forgot to mention that the anchor `<a>` tag isn't self closing. So `<a href="..." >some link</a>` not `<a href="..." />some link</a>`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way that float is handled in the browser.  I recommend if you want to do two columns to either do two wrapping colums around the entire document, or use a grid framework which may help you out in the long run.

I set up a jsfiddle to help illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/a01cv4ec/

**HTML**

```
<h1>Using floats</h1>
<div>
    Only the items you want to distort should be floated...
</div>
<div id="main-page-content">
<div id="balance">
   <u>Balances</u>
<div class="total-balance">
    Total Balance: 
</div>
<div class="a-balance">
    Balance:
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a>
    </div>
<div class="b-balance">
    Balance:
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
    <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="transact">
</div>
<div id="history">     
</div>

<h1>Using inline-block positioning</h1>
<div>
    This personally is my favorite.  Allows for positioning and responsiveness without css hacks to make sure sizes match up.
</div>
<div id="main-page-content-2">
    <div id="col-1">
        <div id="balance">
           <u>Balances</u>
           <div class="total-balance">
                Total Balance: 
           </div>
           <div class="a-balance">
                Balance:
                <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
                <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a>
           </div>
           <div class="b-balance">
                Balance:
                <a href="#" class="button"/>Deposit</a>
                <a href="#" class="button"/>Withdraw</a> 
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="transact">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="column-2">
    <div id="history-inline">     
        history
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-page-content {
   max-width:960px;
   margin:auto;
   max-height: 500px;
   padding-top:25px;
   height:100%;
}

#balance {
    font-family:Lato;
    background-color:#00253F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:130px;
    width:52%;
    float:left;
}

#transact {
    font-family:Lato;
    background-color:#00253F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:130px;
    width:52%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#history {
   background-color:#00253F;
   width:32%;
   margin-left: 58%;
   height:300px; 
}

.total-balance {
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-family:Lato;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    font-size:14px; 
    height:16px;
}

.a-balance {
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-family:Lato;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    font-size:14px; 
    height:16px;
}

.b-balance {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    font-family:Lato;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    font-size:14px; 
    height:16px;
}

.main-page-content-2 {
   width:100%;    
}

.main-page-content-2 > div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    color:#FFF;
}

.main-page-content-2 > div:first-child > div {
    margin:2px;
}


#history-inline {
   color:#FFF;
   background-color:#00253F;
   width:32%;
   margin-left: 58%;
   height:300px; 
}
```

Basically the better way to handle those is either through controlled floats, or even nicer with inline-block positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If the thing you want is to put the history to top of the parent div just because it is like a grid you should use history above your transact.

```
<div id="history">Hist
</div>
<div id="transact">Trans
</div>
```